# The Fermat prime 257 and binomial sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom {8n}{4n}}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, logarithms

We have,

$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom n{n/2}} &= \frac{4}{27}(9-\pi\sqrt{3}\,)\\[2.5mm]
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom {2n}n} &= \frac{4}{5} - \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{25}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\[2.5mm] 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\binom{4n}{2n}}&=\frac{16}{17}+\frac{4\sqrt{34}\,(-2+\sqrt{17}\,)}{289\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{17}}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{17}}}\right)\\&-\frac{2\sqrt{34}\,(2+\sqrt{17}\,)}{289\sqrt{1+\sqrt{17}}} \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{17}}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{17}}-\sqrt{2}}\right)\\[2.5mm]
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom {8n}{4n}} &=\, ???\end{aligned}$

The third one was found by Renzo Sprugnoli. *Question*: Anybody knows a closed-form expression for the fourth one? And will the *Fermat prime p* = 257 appear? (Or is this the law of small numbers again?)

P.S. Strangely, the arguments of the logarithm can be expressed by the Dedekind eta function. Details in my [blog](http://tpiezas.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/fermat-primes-and-binomial-sums/).

**POSTSCRIPT**:

Thanks to Robert Israel's answer, I figured out how to extend it further. His answer (minus the imaginary part) can be expressed as, let,

$\begin{aligned}
x_1&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{1/8}\\
x_2&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{7/8}\end{aligned}$

then,

$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom{8n}{4n}} &= \frac{256}{257}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{x_1\arcsin(x_1)}{(1-x_1^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{x_2\arcsin(x_2)}{(1-x_2^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{x_1\rm arcsinh(x_1)}{(1+x_1^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{x_2\rm arcsinh(x_2)}{(1+x_2^2)^{3/2}} \right)\\ &= 0.985791\dots\end{aligned}$

(So the prime 257 *does* appear!) The form looked susceptible to a generalization so for the next level I tried,

$\begin{aligned}
u_1&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{1/16}\\
u_2&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{3/16}\\
u_3&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{13/16}\\
u_4&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{15/16}\end{aligned}$

$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom{16n}{8n}} &= \frac{65536}{65537}+\frac{1}{8}\left( \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{u_k \arcsin(u_k)}{(1-u_k^2)^{3/2}}-\sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{u_k \rm arcsinh(u_k)}{(1+u_k^2)^{3/2}} \right)\\ &=0.999223\dots\end{aligned}$

which worked, and so on. Since Sprugnoli’s version *has all coefficients and arguments as real numbers*, there might be a way to simplify these sums even further.

Comment: Could you figure out the reference for such formulas?

Comment: @frank: The first two are well known. The third can be found at http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a connection between all of these expressions.
Let
$$ F_k(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2z)^{kn}}{{kn} \choose {kn/2}}$$
In particular $$F_1(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^2} + \frac{z \arcsin(z)}{(1-z^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{\pi z }{2(1-z^2)^{3/2}}$$
Now for $k > 1$, if $\omega_k$ is a primitive $k$'th root of unity we have $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \omega_k^n = k$ if $n$ is divisible by $k$, $0$ otherwise.  So
$$F_k(z) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \omega_k^{jn} \frac{(2z)^{n}}{n \choose {n/2}}= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} F_1(\omega_k^j z)$$
Note that $1/(1-z^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}$ while $\pi z/(2 (1-z^2)^{3/2}$ is an odd function, so if $k$ is even we get
$$F_k(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^{k}} + \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{\omega_k^j z \arcsin(\omega_k^j z)}{(1 - \omega_k^{2j} z^2)^{3/2}}$$

You're interested in the case $z = \omega_k^{1/2}/2$ so that $(2z)^{kn} = (-1)^n$,
thus when $k$ is even $$F_k(\omega_k^{1/2}/2) = \frac{2^k}{2^k + 1} + \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{\omega_k^{j+1/2} \arcsin(\omega_k^{j+1/2}/2)}{2 (1- \omega_k^{2j+1}/4)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for completing the analysis. Now if only we can convert the complex terms into real ones like Sprugnoli's, as it is connected to an observation I made in my blog about a certain "coincidence" between a term and the Dedekind eta function.

Comment: If $0 < t < \pi$, then according to Maple
$$\eqalign{\arcsin \left({{\rm e}^{it}}/2 \right) &=-\arcsin \left( -1/4\,
\sqrt {5+4\,\cos \left( t \right) }+1/4\,\sqrt {5-4\,\cos \left( t
 \right) } \right)\cr  +i &\left( -2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right.\cr &\left.+\ln  \left( 
\sqrt {5+4\,\cos \left( t \right) }+\sqrt {5-4\,\cos \left( t \right) 
}+\sqrt {-6+2\,\sqrt {5+4\,\cos \left( t \right) }\sqrt {5-4\,\cos
 \left( t \right) }} \right)  \right) \cr}
$$

Comment: Ah, the terms will now come as pairs of $(a+bi)(c+di),(a-bi)(c-di)$ and their sum, of course, is the real number $2(ac-bd)$. I know how to take it from here.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be the real part of 
$$
-{\frac {1}{ \left( -1+{\frac {1}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/4}{256}^{3/4}
 \right)  \left( 1+{\frac {1}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/4}{256}^{3/4} \right) 
}}+{\frac {1}{512}}\,{\frac {({-1})^{1/8}{256}^{{ {7}/{8}}}\sqrt 
{1-{\frac {1}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/4} {256}^{3/4}}\arcsin \left( {\frac {1
}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/8}{256}^{{ {7}/{8}}} \right) }{ \left( -1+{
\frac {1}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/4}{256}^{3/4} \right) ^{2}}}-{\frac {1}{
512}}\,{\frac {({-1})^{1/8}{256}^{{ {7}/{8}}}{\rm arcsinh}
 \left( {\frac {1}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/8}{256}^{{ {7}/
{8}}} \right) 
}{ \left( 1+{\frac {1}{256}}\,({-1})^{1/4} {256}^{3/4} \right) ^{3/2}}
}
$$

EDIT: Here's what I did (in Maple 16):

> S0:= sum((-1)^n/binomial(8*n,4*n),n=0..infinity);

$$S0 := {\mbox{$_5$F$_4$}(1/4,1/2,3/4,1,1;\,1/8,3/8,5/8,{\frac {7}{8}};\,-{\frac {1}{256}})}$$

> S1:= subs(-1/256=z,S0);
>
> S2:= convert(S1,FPS,z);

$$S2 := \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( 4\,k \right) !\,{16}^{-k}{z}^{k}}
{{\it pochhammer} \left( 1/4,2\,k \right) {\it pochhammer} \left( 3/4,
2\,k \right) }}
$$

> S3:=  value(S2);

$$S3 := -{\frac {1}{ \left( -1+\sqrt [4]{z} \right)  \left( 1+\sqrt [4]{z}
 \right) }}+1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt [8]{z}\sqrt {1-\sqrt [4]{z}}\arcsin
 \left( \sqrt [8]{z} \right) }{ \left( -1+\sqrt [4]{z} \right) ^{2}}}-
1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt [8]{z}{\it arcsinh} \left( \sqrt [8]{z} \right) }{
 \left( 1+\sqrt [4]{z} \right) ^{3/2}}}
$$

> S4:= eval(S3, z=-1/256);

Somehow this acquired an imaginary part (I suspect because a choice of branch was made in going from S2 to S3).

Comment: So, Tito, is 256 close enough for you?

Comment: @gerrymyerson: well, the minimal polynomial of the arcsinh's and arcsin's argument is $256x^4-1024x^3+1536x^2-1024x+257 = 0$, so $257$ does appear, hehe.

Comment: @Robert Just curious. How did you come up with such an expression?

Comment: @robert: thanks, dr israel! However, there is a typo in the third term. The numerator should start with $(-1)^{1/8}$, not $(-1)^{1/4}$. The expression evaluates to $a+bi$ where $a$ is the desired value. To seal the answer, what is the expression for its conjugate $a-bi$?

Comment: Typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Robert: I figured out a way to get rid of the imaginary part, and generalize your solution. Kindly see the postscript.

Answer (score 1):

Denote our sum by $S_4$. 
\begin{equation}
S_4 := \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom{8 n}{4 n}}
\end{equation}
We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_4 &= & 1-4 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{t^3 (1-t)^4}{[1+t^4 (1-t)^4]^2} dt\\
&=& 1-8 \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{1-4 u}} + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-4 u}}\right) \cdot \frac{u^4}{(1+u^4)^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 u}} du \\
&=&1-4 \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{u^3}{(1+u^4)^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 u}} du \\
&=& \frac{256}{257} + \frac{2}{257} Re[\left(16-i\right) (-1)^{3/4} \cdot \\&&\left(\frac{\left(1+4
   \sqrt[4]{-1}\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4
   \sqrt[4]{-1}}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-4 \sqrt[4]{-1}}}+\frac{\left(4
   \sqrt[4]{-1}-1\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4
   \sqrt[4]{-1}}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+4 \sqrt[4]{-1}}}\right) ]
\end{eqnarray}
In the first line we used the integral representation of the beta function and we resummed the series under the integral. In the second line we substituted for $u=t(1-t)$. In the third line we simplified the result and finally in the last line we substituted for $\sqrt{1-4 u}$.